# I have a error about atmel programs with codevision AVR.My programs give .rom and .hex error

Tags: atmel, atmelstudio, atmel-uc3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2uzq.jpg)I shared my problem in here but ı couldnt solve it.My Project give me an error .rom and .hex.How can I solve it.

My old project can build but i cant my new project can you help me.I deleted Microchip studio and repeat installed it.

Comment: no one can help you without any details ... the error clearly says you are missing a file ...  so most likely you use some lib that you have not installed in your new IDE ... also old IDEs allowed to have more ASF versions installed at once and you could chose which to use in project options ... migration between ASF versions is not easy as they tended to change interfaces a lot so its maybe you have just too new ASF ... also new IDEs do not use just ASF sometimes if you create project wrongly it uses different framework check you main.c if it contains `#include <asf.h>`

Comment: if not then its the case (I saw stuff like `xc.h`, `xc6.h`, `avr32/io.h` instead in some cases) if the case its safest to create new empty ASF project (in new IDE targeting used MCU and board if possible) and copy paste relevant code from old project ....